# Configure IIS to access Deployed website globally (through WAN) [NOTE: I have static IP]

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-7, lan, wan

I am completely new bie to IIS.

I have a very basic knowledge about how to configure IIS.

Today I have a requirement to access website **Globally** through **WAN (through internet from any PC all over world)** which I have deployed in my Local IIS.

The website=> `SilverLightBusinessApplicationWeb`

which you can see in my below screen shot can be open in **LAN** nicely.

so I only looking for how to open it in **WAN**?

So anybody please suggest me a simple steps or instruction for it.

You can see two screen shot of Internet Information Service (IIS) Manager.

**NOTE: 1. I also have static IP     2. i am using IIS7.0 with Windows-7**

Thank you so much…..

**1. Screen Shot1**

[image]

**2. Screen Shot2**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is probably better off on ServerFault. However, providing you have everything set up on your machine, you just need to open and forward port 80 to your host machine and set up a domain or access the site directly via external IP providing your bindings are set up correctly.

**EDIT** From a security point of view, it would be better practice to do as [Germann said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311464/configure-iis-to-access-deployed-website-globally-through-wan-note-i-have-st/11311577#comment14908822_11311577) by having your public facing web server in its own DMZ.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering ....could you please suggest me how to forward port80 to host machine?

Comment: It generally depends on your router and firewall so how you do it is different per device so it's not something I can accurately describe I'm afraid. Though you will also need to open port 80 in your firewall too.

Comment: Then all you need to do is set up port forwarding on your router. Best way to find out is to Google port forwarding for your router manufacturer and model.

Comment: Agreed, though I didn't want to over complicate things in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have got it........
the steps i have followed are......

1. define port forwarding at router for that i have enter following values in my router's forwarding page.

   --IP address of my PC

   --port number which is open(you can see screen shot **Brouse*:80(http)** which shows port 80
   is open for website on my IIS.
2. finally i have opened website on my IIS by : .**http://mystaticip:port/xyzfolder/xyz.html**.